# Generate token from credit card Stripe.Net

Tags: xamarin.forms, stripe-payments, stripe.net

Since `Stripe.Net` doesn't work anymore in the PCL side, we need to use `DependencyServices<>`. However, when I'm trying to generate a token from credit card information, it seems like... It's missing in the doc, I just can't find anything on the web or in the doc, is that normal?

I would like to achieve something like that :

```
public string CardToToken()
{
    var card = new Card()
    {
        Number = "4242424242424242",
        ExpiryMonth = 12,
        ExpiryYear = 16,
        CVC = 123
    };

    try
    {
        token = await Stripe.CreateToken(card);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        return null;
    }

    return token;
}
```

So then I can just simply send it to my server. Any idea to achieve something that easy? That's the last point I need to finish for my project...

This example is in my Android side.

Thank for any help...

Comment: have you tried to call ValidateCard? May be something wrong with the data it expects? May be expiry year 2016 is too old? Or number suppose to have dashes? What does this mean:"It's missing in the doc"? Is token null, do you get exception? BTW, your function CardToToken must be async returning Task<string>. How did you compile that?

Comment: It's like a template of what I'm trying to achieve, of course it doesn't work. Card doesn't exist also and I don't know about validate card..

Comment: So, what answer do you expect? Where to find docs or...?

Comment: I would like to know if my idea/template is the good way to get the token of the card and send it to my server. If I'm right, then where can I find how to generate the token from the entered  information in the doc? Because I read it carefully and I didn't find a way to achieve it, I mean by that get the token of the card

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet and https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

Comment: So I need like a renderer right?

Comment: May be dependancy service but why renderer? It is not a UI

Comment: That's what I'm already doing but I can't use your link , Gradle doesn't exist in Xamarin.Android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153811/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-emixam23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good workaround (only Android at the moment but I will update the answer for UWP soon).

---

**Step 1**

- First, you will have to install `Stripe.Net` over each subplatforms, and I mean by that *Android, iOS, UWP*, not the PCL part (the code you share).

**Step 2**

- To make it work, you will need 3 classes, a model, an interface and another class in your subplatform that inherits from the interface.

The infos you will get should be stored in that class, I did like that, you can achieve it by another way, of course.

In your PCL, declare a **CreditCard.cs**:

```
public class CreditCard
{
    public string Numbers { get; set; }
    public string HolderName { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Cvc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the CreditCard class.
    /// </summary>
    public CreditCard()
    {
        Numbers = "";
        Month = "";
        Year = "";
        Cvc = "";
        HolderName = "";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies the credit card info. 
    /// However, if the data provided aren't matching an existing card, 
    /// it will still return `true` since that function only checks the basic template of a credit card data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the card data match the basic card information. False otherwise</returns>
    public bool VerifyCreditCardInfo()
    {
        if (Numbers == ""
            || Month == ""
            || Year == ""
            || Cvc == ""
            || HolderName == "")
            return false;
        try
        {
            int month = 0;
            int year = 0;
            int cvc = 0;

            if (!Int32.TryParse(Month, out month)
                || !Int32.TryParse(Year, out year)
                || !Int32.TryParse(Year, out cvc))
                return false;

            if (month < 1 || month > 12)
                return false;
            else if (year < 1990 || year > new DateTime().Year)
                return false;
            else if (Cvc.Length != 3)
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception) { return false; }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

- Now that you have your data stored in a class, that's the moment to generate a Stripe token from it ! For that, we'll use the `DependencyServices<>`. So we nee an interface `IStripeServices` in the shared code (PCL), and a service that inherit of it, in the subplatform.

In your PCL, declare a **IStripeServices**

```
public interface IStripeServices
{
    string CardToToken(CreditCard creditCard);
}
```

---

**Android**: Create a **StripeServices** class like that:

```
public class StripeServices : IStripeServices
{
    public string CardToToken(CreditCard creditCard)
    {
        var stripeTokenCreateOptions = new StripeTokenCreateOptions
        {
            Card = new StripeCreditCardOptions
            {
                Number = creditCard.Numbers,
                ExpirationMonth = Int32.Parse(creditCard.Month),
                ExpirationYear = Int32.Parse(creditCard.Year),
                Cvc = creditCard.Cvc,
                Name = creditCard.HolderName
            }
        };

        var tokenService = new StripeTokenService();
        var stripeToken = tokenService.Create(stripeTokenCreateOptions);

        return stripeToken.Id;
    }
}
```

---

**Step 4**

You can now generate a Stripe token from your credit card just by using this piece of code in your shared code (PCL)

```
if (CreditCardData.VerifyCreditCardInfo())
    string cardToken = DependencyService.Get<IStripeServices>().CardToToken(CreditCardData);
else
    Debug.WriteLine("The information are either missing or wrong.");
```

---

I hope this answer will help, I will try create a solution soon on a public github repo for people who wants to test it

Comment: I have implemented your code and its working fine in IOS, but i am getting an exception in the android, which is "mono get runtime build info". This exception comes when code hits the line "var stripeToken = tokenService.Create(stripeTokenCreateOptions);", any idea where i am doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of android? Can you also add the details of the exception, like the exception name or the error message